# Disable package explorer navigation feature (Eclipse) when opening class definition

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I have been looking for this answer in many forums and Eclipses help pages but believe or not i could not find an answer.
I just switched from NetBeans to Eclipse, all is working fine beside one very annoying thing, when i open a class definition in a new editor tab (ctrl+click), Eclipse will also go to that class in the package explorer, i dont want this, the package explorer has to stay as it is, does someone knows how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for a button in the Package Explorer's toolbar named "Link with Editor" and toggle it off.